# How to parse JSON with dynamic key in bigquery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I want to know how to parse JSON if the key is dynamic, and how to define the path in such cases in bigquery?

PFA image with JSON format.
[image: image_json_format]

I am trying to get the `endTime` values in JSON.

I am stuck at `response.data.menus.` and not able to define path post menus as the key is dynamic.

Comment: That's not great sturcture of the data to work with. I would suggest processing that file outside of BQ. Make that key a id field.

Comment: You have labels for all fields except the one that is most important for you. Without a defined structure its not going to be easy for you. Either you do some string manipulation (you can do this manipulation even within GBQ) and convert above json into the json where you have a key name and value field that way you can start programmatically extract things in bigquery.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result so we can better help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, The JSON is very long, hence sharing it in attached gsheet link. You can otherwise refer to screenshot in original post, I want endTime and startTime values as final output. Lmk if you need any more details. PFA sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d4LJ1j9Gd6Tgp0hIKcl0M0jY8t3J7dqZX2IvqxaDtx8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """ 
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_leaves(input string) returns string language js as '''
  function flattenObj(obj, parent = '', res = {}){
    for(let key in obj){
        let propName = parent ? parent + '.' + key : key;
        if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
            flattenObj(obj[key], propName, res);
        } else {
            res[propName] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
  return flattenObj(JSON.parse(input));
  ''';
select *
from (
  select 
    keys[safe_offset(2)] as manu_id, 
    keys[safe_offset(6)] as regularHours, 
    keys[safe_offset(7)] as key, 
    val
  from your_table, unnest([struct(get_leaves(response) as leaves)]),
  unnest(get_keys(leaves)) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(leaves)) val with offset using(offset),
  unnest([struct(split(key, '.') as keys)])
  where ends_with(key, 'startTime')
  or ends_with(key, 'endTime')
)
pivot (any_value(val) for key in ('startTime', 'endTime'))
```

if applied to sample response you provided in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Note: I would not expected above to 100% fit your requirements/expectations  - but at least it should give you good direction!

Comment: Amazing, this will mostly help me, let me reproduce it at my end. Many thanks @mikhail _/\_

Comment: sure. have fun and let us know result :o)