How to Access key and object of json data using Big Query(SQL)
**i have this table which has this json structure **
(https://i.sstatic.net/H3UPCKUO.png)
I want to print a table with name of week , endTime and startTime



WeekDay
EndTime




Monday
00.00


Tuesday
23:59



json structure of UberEats
SELECT * FROM arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours LIMIT 1000;
Tips Given

Please use json parsing and do not use regex.
There is a way to write the SQL without brute forcing all day combinations etc, we would strongly prefer that.
Some starting point that might help How to extract all the keys in a JSON object with BigQuery
Slug is a unique idenfitier for a store
If there are multiple entries for a store, use the one with the latest timestamp.
You can use unnest to flatten business hours array in JSON

I wrote this query and it gave me null for the last column
Query :
SELECT
vb_name AS UberEats_slug,
b_name,
JSON_EXTRACT(response, '$.data.menus[0])
FROM
arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours;
Null value for key object in menus
I tried alternate and it gave me the result only for 1st column as that key differes for all restraunt(slug)
Query :
SELECT
vb_name AS UberEats_slug,
b_name,
JSON_EXTRACT(response, '$.data.menus.26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705.sections[0].regularHours[0].startTime') AS start_time,
JSON_EXTRACT(response, '$.data.menus.26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705.sections[0].regularHours[0].endTime') AS end_time,
FROM
arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours;
Null value except for 1st row
expected result : similar to below image
expected result, s

You have to unnest the the JSON. try using this
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectKeys(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
WITH keys AS (
  SELECT
    jsonObjectKeys(myColumn) AS keys
  FROM
    myProject.myTable
  WHERE myColumn IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT k
FROM keys
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(keys.keys) AS k
ORDER BY k

Do let me know if it works, also show me how you're going about it.

Hi akash can you help me a bit more

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectKeys(input JSON)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE js AS """
return Object.keys(input);
""";
WITH keys AS (
SELECT
jsonObjectKeys(CAST(response AS JSON)) AS keys
FROM
arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours
LIMIT 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT k
FROM
keys
CROSS JOIN
UNNEST(keys) AS k
ORDER BY
k;
I tried this and it is giving error : No matching signature for function jsonObjectKeys for argument types: JSON. Supported signature: jsonObjectKeys(STRING) at [9:5]

Show me what you have done till now, Let me see what can I do.

how? can i show you? can we connect somewhere else? https://www.linkedin.com/in/shreyajha-dtu

also tried this one but still facing error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74087977/how-to-parse-json-with-dynamic-key-in-bigquery a

lets connect to mail, my mail id - akashknewwhat@gmail.com

This link that you provided, i will have to see and understand the function. It might be useful for your answer
